# Where are my all installed programs?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, install, launchpad

I am new to Mac OS X and till the time I was using Windows 7/8. I tried to download and install programs in Mac OS X, but I do not see them in *Launchpad*.

What path contains the software installed on macOS ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All software in Mac OS X is installed in `/Applications`, which can be found in the Finder sidebar

Most Mac applications don't have to be installed, you just have to copy the applications in the Applications folder. Normally, all installed applications that are in the `/Applications` folder appear automatically in the Launchpad.

You can uninstall applications that don't come from the Mac AppStore simply by moving them in the Trash, applications from the Mac AppStore can be uninstall by entering Launchpad, holding the option key and clicking the little x that appears at the app-icon.

The location of the applications folder in the Finder:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

All applications that are included with MacOS are actually located in /System/Applications. Applications installed by the user are located in /Applications. Finder hides this by showing all applications in one combined list.

Answer (score 1):

Under macOS, most programs don't need to be installed they can run from anywhere including the disk you are installing from.

If they are installed, it is usually in `/Applications` (which on later versions of macOS is actually a folder combining `/System/Applications` for programs installed as part of macOS and `/Applications` for others including apps from App Store and others for things like Safari). `/Applications` also has a subdirectory, `Utilities`, that includes some rarer programs like Terminal.app

However, an application can be run from anywhere. It is common for applications for just your user to be in `~/Applications`. Safari is in `/System/Cryptexes/App/System/Applications`. There are system ones in various places in `/System/Library`.

But if you download a `.app` you may save it anywhere and it will usually run. There are apps that check where they are run from.

However, it is possible that if not in the directories listed above then they may not show in Launchpad.